# Trigger click one by one down a list - plus toggle all 

Tags: jquery, keyboard

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/GtXMW/) you can fork and work on

Given a list of

```
<a href="#" class="iconList" id="myDoc_aaa">...</a>
<a href="#" class="iconListChecked" id="myDoc_bbb">...</a>
<a href="#" class="iconList" id="myDoc_ccc">...</a>
```

I want to assign the * key to trigger click on each link in turn and ctrl-* to trigger click on all. I do not want to toggle the class, since there is a script that needs to run when the link is clicked

**QUESTION:** Can you help me with the selectors and what else (data attribute?) to loop over the links one at a time on * and all at once on ctrl-star

So when you

hit *, the first link is triggered (and the script changes the class to  iconListChecked),

hit * star again and the second link is triggered (unchecking it),

hit * and the third is triggered,

hit * and we wrap and the first is triggered (unchecking it)

---

hit ctrl-star and all not-checked links are triggered

**FIXED**: `$(".iconList").trigger("click");`

---

(My fiddle currently only handles the * on the numeric keyboard - I have a separate question for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841232/how-to-get-at-the-star-above-the-numbers))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/GtXMW/28/

```
// ... removed unedited part..

// Function to handle *
function toggleFirst() {
    var $candidates = $('.iconList,.iconListChecked');
    var $nottoggled = $candidates.not('.rw_toggled').first();
    if (!$nottoggled.length) {
        // There is no non-toggled element any more.
        // Remove class from all links
        $candidates.removeClass('rw_toggled');
        $nottoggled = $candidates.first();
    }
    // Add temporary class, trigger click
    $nottoggled.addClass('rw_toggled').click();
    console.log("*");
}
// Function to handle ctrl+*
function toggleAll() {
    console.log("ctrl+*");
    $(".iconList").click();
}    
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Handle Ctrl+* and * 
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (e.which === 42) { // '*'.charCodeAt(0) === 42
            if (!$this.data('rw_star_pressed')) {
                $this.data('rw_star_pressed', true);
                if (e.ctrlKey) { // Ctrl + *
                    toggleAll();
                } else {             // Just *
                    toggleFirst();
                }
            }
        }
    }).keyup(function() {
        $(this).removeData('rw_star_pressed');
    });

    // ... rest of your original code...
});
```

Comment: Nice one too - thanks. And you fixed the number row *. Dilemma - who to accept

Comment: @mplungjan Just pick the one which provided the most complete answer to the question. That's the purpose of it.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as how you've solved part of it yourself, I believe this should help with the rest: http://jsfiddle.net/D4PhQ/4/

By using the class `next` it tracks the next one to click and then uses `.next()` to find the next `a` element in the page.

```
function toggleFirst() {
    console.log("*");
    var n = $(".next").first();
    n.click();
    n.removeClass("next");
    n.nextAll("a").addClass("next");
    if (n.nextAll("a").length === 0) $("a").addClass("next");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking. I get `n.next.addClass is not a function`

Comment: @mplungjan Fixed it, try again.

Comment: Thanks - got a more complete answer from Rob.