# How to get keypress of the star above the numbers

Tags: jquery, events, keyboard

**QUESTION:**  how to get at the star above the numbers

My [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/GtXMW/)  currently does not detect the * above the number row on the keyboard - only the * on the numeric keypad...

On my keyboard it is shift-3 so keyCode 51 + shift. How do I just test for * regardless of what I clicked to get it?

Comment: Converting `event.which` using `String.fromCharCode` is only reliable at the `keypress` event.

Comment: I see its detecting `*`. But the problem is it also detects `8` as `*`.

Comment: @RobW but that only works if all keyboards returned the same number for the character on the key. In my case 51 is * and on US it is 56

Comment: @mplungjan No, it does not work. The `keydown` and `keyup` events return the codes for the keys, *not* for the pressed character. `8` and `*` will return the same keycode -> `event.which`. As I mentioned before, only the `keypress` event can be relied on.

Comment: @RobW so please post an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keydown` and `keyup` events are unreliable for detecting specific characters, because the [`event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) property of these events are **not** char codes.

The `keypress` event has to be used. This event may fire multiple times whilst a key is pressed down. So, set a flag when the desired key is pressed, and remove the flag on `keyup`.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xHnTD/

```
function something_to_do() {
    // This function is fired when * is pressed.
    $('<div>Pressed *!</div>').appendTo('body')
}
$('body').keypress(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (e.which === 42) { // '*'.charCodeAt(0) === 42
        if (!$this.data('rw_star_pressed')) {
            $this.data('rw_star_pressed', true);
            something_to_do();
        }
    }
}).keyup(function() {
    $(this).removeData('rw_star_pressed');
});
```

Comment: The fiddle On OSX I get 56,8 on the * above my 8 which at work would be above 3. 
I get 106 on the numeric keyboard. 
Seems your code posted here works. I do need to see if I pressed ctrl-* too

Comment: @mplungjan Oops Wrong demo link. Edited answer :p

Comment: Can you add ctrl-* too please?

Comment: I found e.ctrlKey so no need to fix this. I will look at the other question

Comment: I accepted yours here. I like the next() method given in the other question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about the keycodes you posted.
With this code, when I press `*` I get `56`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function( event ) { 
             console.log(event.keyCode); });
</script>
```

Comment: I know. I get 51 on my swiss-german keyboard - so not an answer.